# AWS Sagemaker - "Hidden file found in the data path! Remove that before training."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to train a model using Amazon Sagemaker (xgboost: eu-west-1': '685385470294.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest'). But I always get the same error message shortly after starting the training job:

> "ClientError: Hidden file found in the data path! Remove that before
>   training."

The S3 console shows that output path is empty (I also tried to create a new directory to no avail). Versioning is not enabled for the bucket.

Surprisingly, google finds nothing under this error message.

I have configured the input and outputs as follows:

```
   "InputDataConfig": [
        {
            "ChannelName": "train",
            "DataSource": {
                "S3DataSource": {
                    "S3DataType": "S3Prefix",
                    "S3Uri": "s3://{}/{}-inputdata/train".format(s3_utils.bucket, LABEL)
                }
            },
            "ContentType": "csv",
            "CompressionType": "None"
        },
        {
            "ChannelName": "validation",
            "DataSource": {
                "S3DataSource": {
                    "S3DataType": "S3Prefix",
                    "S3Uri": "s3://{}/{}-inputdata/validation".format(s3_utils.bucket, LABEL)
                }
            },
            "ContentType": "csv",
            "CompressionType": "None"
        }
    ],
    "OutputDataConfig": {
        "S3OutputPath": "s3://{}/{}-xgboost-output".format(s3_utils.bucket, LABEL)        },
```

The field

```
    "RoleArn": role,
```

where role comes from

```
    from sagemaker import get_execution_role
    role = get_execution_role()
```

and is

```
    arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT>:role/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-<HIDDEN>
```

Here is a screenshot showing the data-path:
[S3 dashboard view of data-path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs8kl.png). The two csv files is all there is. In particular, there is no empty "directory" which might be what "hidden file" could mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, the prefix you set in the `S3Uri` matters here. Based on your screenshot I think your bucket looks something like this (in tree form):

```
s3://bucket
└── LABEL-inputdata
    ├── train.csv
    └── validation.csv
```

Based on your `InputDataConfig` above, SageMaker has to download it to folders on the filesystem for the `xgboost` training algorithm to run. It does so based on the channel names and on the `S3Uri` prefix you provided. The prefix is chopped off to determine the name of the folder/file to download to. So, in your example, the `train` channel gets downloaded as:

```
/opt/ml/input/data/train/.csv
```

Finally, the `xgboost` implementation sees the `.csv` file as a hidden file and complains about it.

To get it to work you could rearrange your data in s3 like so...

```
s3:bucket
└── LABEL-inputdata
    ├── train
    │   └── data.csv
    └── validation
        └── data.csv
```

.. and change your input data config to:

```
   "InputDataConfig": [
        {
            "ChannelName": "train",
            "DataSource": {
                "S3DataSource": {
                    "S3DataType": "S3Prefix",
                    "S3Uri": "s3://{}/{}-inputdata/train/".format(s3_utils.bucket, LABEL)
                }
            },
            "ContentType": "csv",
            "CompressionType": "None"
        },
        {
            "ChannelName": "validation",
            "DataSource": {
                "S3DataSource": {
                    "S3DataType": "S3Prefix",
                    "S3Uri": "s3://{}/{}-inputdata/validation/".format(s3_utils.bucket, LABEL)
                }
            },
            "ContentType": "csv",
            "CompressionType": "None"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've seen this one before... Could you please check the S3 training and validation locations? There shouldn't be anything there but the training and validaton files.

Comment: I also had en empty "directory" (not that there is such a thing as a directory for S3) which might have been the "hidden file". But that was not it. I added a screenshot of the S3 dashboard showing the contents of the data path. The two data files is all there is. I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and there was no **Hidden file**.

I used cascade of trainings. PCA and then I used result from PCA in the XGBoost.
I used **recordio-protobuf** format for PCA and chose file extension **rio**. First training (PCA) passed well and second (XGBoost) failed.
After removing file **train.rio** second training passed well.
Then I decided to rename file **train.rio** into **train.bin** and everything works fine now.

It a bit strange behavior as for me. File with extension **rio** is a *Hidden file**...